# How to addEvent to two different <p:schedule>

Tags: primefaces

I have two  and I am adding events, but I need to mark in two calendars the range I select, for example if I select from March 21st to April 10th in the first calendar will be marked until the 30th, and the other one marked from April 1st to 10th,

Do you have any idea?

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the same object instance of `ScheduleEvent` to achieve that, you need 2 instances.

You could simply implement your own `ScheduleEvent` with a copy constructor. Therefore just inherit from `DefaultScheduleEvent':

```
class CustomScheduleEvent extends DefaultScheduleEvent
{
    public CustomScheduleEvent(ScheduleEvent org)
    {
        super(org.getTitle(), org.getStart(), org.getEnd()); //or any other super constructor

        //init other attributes...
    }
}
```

Now you can copy your event like this:
`ScheduleEvent newEvent = new CustomScheduleEvent(orgEvent);` and set the new one.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I did and it worked, Thanks i cant mark it as the right answer but it is... Thanks

Comment: Well if this satisfied your needs, it should be marked though. Is there someting other you were hoping for?